# No matching records found en DataTable con laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax, json, datatables

Estoy haciendo una búsqueda personalizada con Datatable en laravel pero no se pinta el resultado

```
                var table2= $('#tabla_asistencia_alumno').DataTable({
                   processing: true,
                   serverSide: true,
                   ajax:{
                    url:'/buscar-asistencia-alumno',
                    method:"GET",
                    data:{añoCarrera:añoCarrera, semestreCarrera:semestreCarrera},
                    dataSrc: ""
                  },
                  Columns:[
                  {data:'NOMBRE_CURSO',name:'NOMBRE_CURSO'},
                  {data:'seccion',name:'seccion'},
                  {data:'CODE',name:'CODE'}
                  ]
                });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor agrega el código como texto y no como imagen.

Comment: Hola Togos 4. Las preguntas con imágenes de código no son bien recibidas porque es muy difícil manejarlo así para su revisión y poder ofrecer ayuda. Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.